# ClosedXML reading empty cell and increasing count

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, closedxml

I am reading excel file with ClosedXML,
I have data in 1 single Column A1.A2.A3... all A columns,

When I open excel and delete A2.A3 and keep only single value in A1 and save excel,

after that when I upload file to file control it uploads file and prints 3 even though I have single data in A1.

it reads data and insert into array as [ "123482", "", "" ] <- it is considering deleted rows as empty data and I am not able to skip these empty data any help?

**Sample Data in Excel: _ <= Blank Line**
| **Voucher** |
| -------- |
| 123456 |
| _ // This is an empty line in excel with using DELETE Key on Keyboard |
| _ // This is an empty line in excel with using DELETE Key on Keyboard |
| _ // This is an empty line in excel with using DELETE Key on Keyboard |
| _ // This is an empty line in excel with using DELETE Key on Keyboard |

Sample Code **READING EXCEL FILE**:

```
public DataTable readExcelFile(System.IO.Stream inputExcelFile)
    {
        // to bind data table to gridview
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        // creating new workbook object and sending Uploaded File as input File
        using (XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook(inputExcelFile))
        {
            // creating excel worksheet object to access worksheet from workbook(Excel File)
            IXLWorksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheet(1);

            // initializing 1st row
            bool firstRow = true;
            foreach (IXLRow row in sheet.Rows())
            {
                // printing 1st row as headers of Table DATA
                if (firstRow)
                {
                    // getting cells of 1st row
                    foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
                    {
                        // adding full 1st row cells into data table
                        dt.Columns.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
                    }
                    // making 1st row = false as 1st is finished
                    firstRow = false;
                    continue; // go to next row
                }
                else {
                    // adding empty rows in sheet
                    dt.Rows.Add();
                    int i = 0;
                // getting cells in rows
                foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
                {
                        // to stop Row indexer we use row count - 1 as it loops
                        // it always keep row to row - 1 to add value to corrent row
                        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell.Value.ToString();
                        i++;             
                    }
                }

                // setting data source to gridview
                //GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                // binding data to gridview
                //GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

CALLING FUNCTION WHICH HAS DATATABLE FROM ABOVE READING:

```
// converting Array into JSon String
excelSerialArrayToJson(excelReaderdt);
```

**DATA TABLE ROW TO ARRAY**

```
private void excelSerialArrayToJson(DataTable excelInputdt)
    {
        // initializing serials Array Length to DataTable Row Length
        serials = new String[excelInputdt.Rows.Count];
        // For each row, print the values of each column.
        // 2 rows  - ROW 0 -- Row 1
        for (int i = 0; i < excelInputdt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            // 1 column
            for (int j = 0; j < excelInputdt.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                // initializing serials Array
                serials[i] = excelInputdt.Rows[i][j].ToString();
            }
        }
```

My Desired output should be

1. **Output I want** Serials[] = ("123456") - COUNT = 1
2. **Output I am Getting**| = Serials[] = ("123456","","","") - COUNT = 4

Array Count should be 1 as it has only 1 entry which is **123456**

Comment: Could you give me some code snippets? Add some filter conditions similar to `value!=null`.

Comment: I have Edit my question with sample code for your reference please check

Comment: How you create excel file? Even through you are deleting columns Excel not modified table object. You can test it by select cell A1 and press Ctrl+End. After you delete some columns with not modified table object, cursor will be placed into last row of right border yearly created table object. Delete column operation only clear stored data, but not change table object. So, when you get a excel row, you get not only data from column A1, you get all data from this table object. If you copy A1 column to new sheet, and delete original sheet - it solves your problem

Comment: but here I am reading excel file and then storing column A1 data into an array, the excel file will always only have values in Column A1, even though it is reading full excel sheet regardless of number of columns & rows, the only issue I am facing is when I read excel and print in gridview it prints fine, but when I log my Array in console or print in textView I get result as {"1234556", "","",""} and array count becomes 4, but requirement is when array count is 1 it should print result in webpage, if arraycount>1 then it should generate excel file as result,

Comment: I tried for arrayCount>1 I am able to generate accurate and perfect results, but I cannot get arrayCount = 1 to run this condition, if only I can edit array and remove any null values in it, the problem will be solved, or from DataTable when reading excel I can skip null/empty cells will also solve my problem, I know the solution but the approach I don't have an Idea how I can achieve it.

Comment: Can you use `const string fileUrl ="";XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook(fileUrl);`? I cannot reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it by geting number of column of last used cell in row 1, instead of counting columns:

```
excelInputdt.Row(1).LastCellUsed().Address.ColumnNumber
```

You can check if this would work for you by counting used cells in last column, and if you get 0, then this should work.

```
excelInputdt.Column(excelInputdt.Columns().Count()).CellsUsed().Count()
```